# need for CDN for website in one small country?

Tags: latency, cdn

I sometimes make websites for businesses that trade only within the UK. If I am only interested in visitors from within the same country where the origin server is based, and the country is relatively small, is there any point at all in using a CDN?

Do people only use CDN's to benefit from edge locations reducing latency or is there anything else useful that they can do? And how dispersed are edge locations for the average CDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do people only use CDN's to benefit from edge locations reducing
>   latency or is there anything else useful that they can do?

Yes, say they need to distribute video to over a few hundred thousand people, the load is massively reduced on the source origin system if you use a CDN.

> And how dispersed are edge locations for the average CDN?

There is no such thing as an average CDN, they're all massively different but generally speaking the UK's very well covered for most areas with only the non-city parts of Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland less covered.